# Odd C++ accessing private member issue

Tags: c++

I have this piece of code:

```
class object
{

public:
    virtual ~object(){ }

    bool equals(const object& J)const
    {
        return &J == this;
    }
    int operator==(const object& J)const
    {
        return equals(J);
    }
    virtual int getHash()const;
    virtual void getType()const;
    void* operator new(size_t size)
    {
        void*mem = malloc(size);
        return mem;
    }
};

class notcopyable
{
private:
    notcopyable(const notcopyable&){}
    notcopyable& operator=(const notcopyable&){}
public:
    notcopyable(){}
};

class exception :
    public object,public notcopyable
{
private:
public:
    virtual ~exception();
    virtual const char* info();
};

class exception_not_implemented :
    public exception
{
public:
    exception_not_implemented()
    {
    }
    virtual const char* info()
    {
        return "exception_not_implemented: ";
    }
};

class exception_oob :public exception
{
public:
    exception_oob()
    {

    }
    virtual const char* info()
    {
        return "Index out of boundary";
    }
};
```

There are two functions throw exception_not_implemented:

```
void object::getType()const
{
    throw exception_not_implemented();
}

int object::getHash()const
{
    throw exception_not_implemented();
}
```

And getting this error:

```
error C2248: 'js::notcopyable::notcopyable' : cannot access private member declared in class 'js::notcopyable'
```

The output of the compiler says:

```
This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'js::exception::exception(const js::exception &)'
```

If I delete the two throw shown above, it works well. But the same error doesn't happens to exception_oob. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Are you sure the error is here, not somewhere else in your program?

Comment: This code compiles fine for me.

Comment: @EduardoLeón it might be... Because the line number points to the last line shown in my code.

Comment: @DavidBrown Oh my... I don't know what happens in my code... There is one more class public inherits exception called exception_not_implemented. Does this matter?

Comment: the error is not occured here. msvc should print you some more details after this error (but not enough). like `... : see declaration of ...` and than something like `This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'foo::(const foo &)'`. you try to copy your notcopyable class or a child somewhere. this even could be catching the exception by value instead of reference. also you shouldn't inherite notcopyable as public.

Comment: so what do you want? to be able to copy `class exception`, then don't inherit from notcopyable, or to not be able to copy, then just don't copy.

Comment: @itwasntpete I tried to copy an exception object to test my code but then I deleted it... The strange thing was that when I tested it, it worked. But after deleting, it began to show this error... Please see my update, seems the problem comes from the default generated copy ctor of class exception...

Comment: how should class exception be possible to copy if you want to forbid it by inheriting from notcopyable?

Comment: @itwasntpete Yeah I just wanted to make sure it worked by seeing the error message... But after deleting the copy statement the error didn't go.

Comment: and you are really, really, really sure, you are looking at the right place? you have to find out where the error occurs. the code snippet you posted is fine.

Comment: @itwasntpete Hmmm, now I can't say I'm sure about it. I explicitly defined a copy ctor, the error is gone, but the ctor is not called at all.

Comment: What is "js"?  Is it namespace or something more.  Paste the full or more of the code.

Comment: @Eric Yeah it's a namespace. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily add a private copy constructor declaration, which will generate an error at the point where a copy is being made.  Then you can fix that code to not make copies.

Comment: I explicitly defined a copy ctor and it's not called at all... I'm writing some templates in the same header. Does this matter?

Comment: @babel92: If you don't get an error because it is private, possibly the rogue copy occurs in a context that has access to private constructors (member or friend).  If you declare it without defining it, do you get an unresolved external error?

Comment: Not really... Seems that the error is due to private access. And there is no linking problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error should happen at other place where you call the (private) copy constructor.

For example:

Exception a;
Exception b = a;  // error : cannot access private member ...

Comment: @babel: Then some of your other code is unintentionally calling the copy constructor.

Comment: @BenVoigt I explicitly defined a copy ctor and the error is gone, but the function is not called at all.

Comment: @babel92: There are a few conditions where the actual call can be elided, but the compiler is still required to check that the copy constructor exists...

Comment: @BenVoigt I really don't think anywhere in my code calls the copy constructor... I'm writing some templates in the same header. Does this matter?